# Setting the DataGridView AllowUserToResizeColumns is not 100% correct

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

If I set a the DataGridView to:

```
dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dataGridView.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
```

And then set my columns like this:

```
dataGridView.Columns["Colour"].FillWeight = 50;
dataGridView.Columns["Layer"].FillWeight = 50;
cboColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(16, 0, 16, 0);
```

It initially looks great:

[image: Good Grid]

I purposely put the mouse over the column resize and it won't allow. Good! But ...

I can still resize the column on the left, and when I do that, my painting on the right looks bad:

[image: Error]

So I have two issues here:

1. Why is it that I can still resize the first column? I don't want to allow it.
2. If it must be allowed, can we deal with the last column issue?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have fixed row header width and prevent users from resizing row header width, you can set [`RowHeadersWidthSizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheaderswidthsizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your grid to `DisableResizing` using designer or code:

```
grid.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
```

This way the size of row headers would be the fixed value which you set using  [`RowHeadersWidth`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowheaderswidth(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your data grid view control.

You can also use auto size options of [`DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159167(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration.

> By default, users can resize the width of the row headers. You can
>   disable this ability to set a fixed width, or you can use a
>   content-based automatic sizing mode, which also disables user
>   resizing.

Comment: Great! Seems strange to have two settings. But thanks all the same. :)

Comment: Read also the quote.